# Find element by its children attribute value in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the below html structure:

```
<ul class="dpt1 yui-dt-ul ui-sortable">
      <li class="dpt1 yui-dt-first dpt1 yui-dt-even">
          <input class="sort" type="hidden" data-sort="1" data-rule-id="8337" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511"/>
          <a class="CSSprite btn16 ed etib" title="Edit rule" href="#" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" data-rule-id="8337">Edit rule</a>
          <a class="CSSprite btn16 nuke etib" title="Delete rule" href="#" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" data-rule-id="8337">Delete rule</a>
          Price New 2010 Dodge Avenger cars at List Price - $300 (Discount: -300) Sort Order:
          <input class="sorttextbox" type="text" maxlength="5" data-sort="1" data-rule-      id="8337" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" value="1"/>
      </li>

      <li class="dpt1 yui-dt-odd WarnMsg">
          <input class="sort" type="hidden" data-sort="2" data-rule-id="9100" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511"/>
          <a class="CSSprite btn16 ed etib" title="Edit rule" href="#" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" data-rule-id="9100">Edit rule</a>
          <a class="CSSprite btn16 nuke etib" title="Delete rule" href="#" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" data-rule-id="9100">Delete rule</a>
          Price New 2008 zzTEST Grand Caravan C/V Gas V6 3.3L/202 cars at List Price Sort Order:
          <input class="sorttextbox" type="text" maxlength="5" data-sort="2" data-rule-      id="9100" data-ruletype="2" data-dpt="1" data-cid="1511" value="2"/>
      </li>
</ul>
```

can some body advise how can I get the li element by its children input tag data-sort value?

Comment: use `.closest()` or even `.parent()` is fine also close voted your question as you haven't tried it yourself first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `<li>` element that has an input child with `data-sort="1"`, then you could do that like this:

```
$("ul li input[data-sort='1']").closest("li");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 $("input[data-sort='1']").parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the parent li element by its children input tag `data-sort` attribute value:

```
var attributevalue = "1"; //-- Enter your desired `data-sort` value        
$("input[data-sort='" + attributevalue + "']").parent();
```

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uZM7/)